# Django: отправка по email

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib

Я хочу, чтобы, когда пользователь сбрасывал пароль, к нему на почту приходило письмо с ссылкой на сброс пароля. Но, насколько я понял, `send_mail` в Django больше не работает, так как Django использует smtplib, а Google не считает, что она безопасная, а потому выдает ошибку: `SMTPAuthenticationError`.

Есть ли какие-нибудь другие способы отправки email? Или, может, есть варианты использовать smtplib без ошибок?

Comment: вы можете поместить ваше приложение в список ненадежных приложений, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту. Сделать это можно по [этой](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) ссылке

Comment: @Dmitry, эта тема уже не работает. Google перестал разрешать подобные действия(

Answer (score 2):

Нашел я ответ(спустя 6 часов поисков) - https://habr.com/ru/post/675130/
Всего-то нужно было включить двухфакторную аутентификацию в аккаунте, с которого вы собираетесь отправлять письмо. Далее в "Пароли приложений" добавить этот аккаунт и выданный гуглом пароль вставить в EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD в настройках приложения. Зайдите по ссылке: много читать не придется.